# why schema is not created in mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server

[image]

I am doing development on Mac, I downloaded mysql sever and workbench. It is not creating schema. In the morning I went through some tutorial and was able to make a table or every thing. But due to some reason I deleted workbench and sql server. Now I re-installed both and created schema, it not able to create.

Can you please tell me why it is occurring?![image]

Comment: Did you check may be TEST schema already exists?

Comment: it is not taking any name..:(

Comment: it is giving same error in all name  ? same error in all ?

Comment: No, just simple question, TEST is common name. But if with another name there is still problem, it is not the reson.

Comment: it mean that i am not able to scema ..

Answer (score -1):

By default, MySQL comes with a schema called 'test' already. Try creating a schema with a different name.

Comment: see the comment above, he try the different names